# How to use location.replace for a hash

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to redirect users without reloading the page. So if the user clicks on `<a href="#link1">` it should redirect to `#link2`.

The problem is, if I use `location.hash="link2"`, it adds 2 entries in the history, which I don't want, because when the user clicks on the back button, it goes to `link1`, and then redirects to `link2`, so the user basically can't go back without opening the list of visited pages.

And if I use `location.replace`, it reloads the whole page from the server, which I don't want either.

Does anyone have a way to redirect the user without adding a new history entry?

I do not want to use `replaceState` because of backward compatibility with browsers that don't support HTML5.
I also don't want to use something like `event.preventDefault()` so that users can bookmark the link in their browser and it would work the same way.

Comment: Are you setting `location.hash` as an onclick event of the link?

Comment: I might be missing something vital here, but why don't you just link to `#link2`?

Comment: Because I want to redirect to a dynamic string that depends on other things, not a static string like `link2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [window.history.replaceState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history).

Comment: I just edited the question, I could use this solution but I want to support older browsers

Comment: could you add a shim/polyfill to handle older browsers?  such as https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/

Comment: Just tried that, and it still creates another history entry

Answer (score 0):

You could also just handle the onclick event with JavaScript and jQuery and scroll to the anchor without triggering the browser. **[Here is an example](http://bradsknutson.com/blog/smooth-scrolling-to-anchor-with-jquery/)** with jQuery's **`.animate()`** function for smooth scrolling